# Cart total is not calculated correctly

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have unusual problem..in my sylius project when I add 2 products to the cart, cart total is not correct. It is always less than it should be, even though there are no discounts or adjustments attached to the products. I have not changed sylius original logic behind that, but I have changed ChannelPricing entity and added fields oldPrice and discount. I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it. I tried reverting to see would it change anything, but no luck.[image: You can see how it's calculating it wrong]
[image: You can see here the difference between unitPrice and total]
This is my code for channelpricing:

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelPricing as BaseChannelPricing;


class ChannelPricing extends BaseChannelPricing
{

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $oldPrice;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    protected $discount;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOldPrice()
    {
        return $this->oldPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $oldPrice
     */
    public function setOldPrice($oldPrice)
    {
        $this->oldPrice = $oldPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDiscount()
    {
        return $this->discount;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $discount
     */
    public function setDiscount($discount)
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
 }`
```

And

```
 sylius_core:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    resources:
        channel_pricing:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ChannelPricing
```

Also code for the form extension

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Product\ChannelPricingType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\Form\Type\MoneyType;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PercentType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class ChannelPricingTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                /** @var ChannelInterface $channel */
                $channel = $event->getData()->getChannel();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $form->remove('price')
                    ->add('oldPrice',MoneyType::class,[
                    'label' => 'Stara cijena',
                    'currency' => $channel->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                ])
                ->add('discount',PercentType::class,[
                    'label' => 'Popust',

                ])->add('price',MoneyType::class,[
                    'label' => 'Cijena',
                    'currency' => $channel->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                ]);
            })
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return ChannelPricingType::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error due to versioning I imagine.. after I updated it to the latest dev-master it is working as expected, and I can't reproduce it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the ChannelPricing modification changes everything. Did you try to see what is saved on the ChannelPricing related to your OrderItem?